# data get requests from a website with unsupported browser error

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

i have basically tried everything but still i get the unsupported browser error. i use requests module. i have tried with headers, other modules but still the same.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.ratemyagent.com.au/"
response = requests.get(url)
html_icerigi = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerigi, "html.parser")
```

https://www.ratemyagent.com.au/ this is the adres. so please if you have any idea to get rid of this error let me know.

thanks a lot in advance

edit: this is what i have tried as headers :

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36' headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent } response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

versions // python 3. BeautifulSoup4: 4.6.0 requests:2.20
[this is the output with soup.text or reponse.text][1]

Comment: Can't reproduce error, receiving HTTP 200 from the request

Comment: but when you print the text just unsupported browser

Comment: What headers have you tried?  Specifically, what `User-Agent` headers?

Comment: user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

Comment: this is what i have tried

Comment: maybe it s something to do with certification?

Comment: Check your `user-agent` like @JohnGordon suggested. Cant reproduce error. I get a 200 as well. It has nothing to do with certificates. Check user-agent. You can use https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/ to ease choosing user agents.

Comment: i have just tried it now with several browsers but still the same thing. unsupported browser. @PruthviKumar. thanks for helps.

Comment: what version of python, requests and BS4 are you using? @uestadeus

Comment: python 3.7 , bs4 0.01, requests 2.20 @PruthviKumar

Comment: even after get request of the url i print out and i recieve always unsupported error. i mean when u try do u have different result ? am i missing somethinng @PruthviKumar?  response = requests.get(url,headers=header) print(response.text) then same result....

Comment: bs4 version 0.0.1??? That sounds weird. I get a 200 for just the same code above. Details: Py -3, Requests - 2.18.4, BeautifulSoup4 - 4.6.0

Comment: yeah sorry i checked the wrong thing mine also 4.6.0. but when u try to get the text. do u see also unsupported browser ? i get also 200 but with text i can not reach the source of the code @PruthviKumar

Comment: please [edit] your additional info such as headers, BS4 version into the question.

Comment: No error occured on my bs4-4.5.1 requests-2.20.1 python35

Comment: but what do u have as an output? so not same as i shared in edited info ? @kcorlidy, i really need help, otherwise i ll get crazy) thanks everybody again for your helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### it's `not a error`

#### when you normally search `https://www.ratemyagent.com.au/` by `chrome browser`, the page resource your get also has the info like you said:

[image]

#### while the resource your get by requests module is same as what you get from a web browser I don't think it is a error.